# Java Regex search two file names

Tags: java, regex

I need some help with Java regular expressions.
I have two files:

```
file_201111.txt.gz
file_2_201111.txt.gz
```

I need a regular expression to search both the files.

If I use `file_[0-9]+.txt.gz` I get the first file if I use `file_[0-9]_[0-9]+.txt.gz` I get the second file.

How can I combine both search patterns to search for the two files?

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the [`java.util.regex.Pattern` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) you will find a couple different options. In the _Logical operators_ section you will see the `|` _Either X or Y_, or `X?` _X, once or not at all_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to indicate that the optional unit is optional with `?`. And since it is a multi-character unit, you should group it with `()`. Try this:

```
file(_[0-9])?_[0-9]+\\.txt\\.gz
```

Comment: file_([0-9])?_[0-9]+.txt.gz returned only file_2_201111.txt.gz , tried this file_(_[0-9])?_[0-9]+.txt.gz returned nothing , I need both the files with one expression

Comment: @sriharikalicharanTummala Neither of those two you tried are the one I gave you. The first one, the `_` is outside the `()` when it should be inside, the second one, you've added an extra `_`. Just copy and paste exactly what I put in my answer.

Comment: This will match `file_11txt.gz`

Answer (score 3):

### Brief

Since you haven't specified the actual format for all the files, I'll present you with a couple of regular expressions and you can use whichever best matches your needs.

---

### Code

#### Method 1

This matches an arbitrary number of `_` and digits.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/V6SD2r/1)

```
file[_\d]+\.txt\.gz
```

For all the *haters*, yes it will match `file_.txt.gz`, so to prevent that you can use [`file(?:_\d+)+\.txt\.gz`](https://regex101.com/r/V6SD2r/3) instead.

#### Method 2

This matches one or two of the `_number` pattern where `number` represents any number (1+ digits).

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/V6SD2r/2): Both patterns below accomplish the same thing.

```
file(?:_\d+){1,2}\.txt\.gz
file_\d+(?:_\d+)?\.txt\.gz
```

---

### Explanation

#### Method 1

- `file` Match this literally
- `[_\d]+` Match one or more of any character in the set (`_` or digit)
- `\.txt\.gz` Match this literally (note that `\.` matches a literal dot character `.`)

#### Method 2

- `file` Match this literally
- `(?:_\d+){1,2}` Match `_\d+` (underscore followed by one or more digits) once or twice

  - Note that the second option `_\d+(?:_\d+)?` is essentially the same.
- `\.txt\.gz` Match this literally (note that `\.` matches a litearl dot character `.`)